# How to use NVelocity without embedding the templates as resources?

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource, nvelocity

I've been playing around with NVelocity to create a library that loads mail templates. And I haven't been able to load a template without embedding it into the application assembly. Is there a special way of doing this? Properties to be specified?

I've tried several string formatting tweaks to get the path of the template and keep getting an exception of wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Check out: [Template merging with NVelocity and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/nvelocityaspnet.aspx)

There is also a fork of NVelocity at: [CodePlex](http://nvelocity.codeplex.com/) which appears to be somewhat newer than both the original version and the castle fork.

Comment: That's an old version. I'm working with the latest one from Castle Project.